# mysql problem with login in terminal

Tags: 12.04, mysql

I read many post including https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset this one one all of method. How much time I do this I don't know. Still my problem was't fixed. I already wasted 6 more hour for installing mysql. Still it shows:

```
sohel@sohel:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' 
(using password: YES)
```

//when i try with this

```
sohel@sohel:~$ 140411 18:37:31 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer 
instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. 
Please use the full name instead.
mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

//so i use Another way, purge

**Then repeat the same problem**

What should i do now plz help someone .If i reinstall ubuntu will solve this problem.
Is any file missing is my system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a password set for the MySQL root user, but you are not using the same password now.  The link you posted has the correct solution.  The following commands should get you in:

```
sudo killall mysqld
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
mysql
```

Then, in the MySQL client:

```
set @password = password('your new password');
update mysql.user set Password=@password where User='root';
```

Once you've done that, you'll want to run `sudo service mysql restart` and try getting in as root again.